# OSB Jdeveloper Application Project reference

Tags: jdeveloper, osb

I amusing Jdeveloper 12C, 12.1.3 to be exact.
Anyone know how to reference a project in a difference application.
This get a little more complicated since it is for Oracle Service Bus projects.

For example
I have 2 Applications AppA and AppB 
ProjectA is in AppA and ProjectB is AppB.
I need to reference the ProjectB in ProjectA.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must `deploy AppA to create jar files` (right click on project and click deploy). Add these `jar files to your AppB` to use your ProjectA in ProjectB. (either in library folder locally or you can use Maven to automate this process)

Comment: I am after Oracle service bus applications and not Java projects.